# SwiftUI Widget fails to refresh

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm trying to create a widget on SwiftUI. The widget is supposed to refresh every hour. However, the widget fails to reload.

While troubleshooting noticed that the widget does update when I manually change the time from settings.

```
func getTimeline(for configuration: MyWidgetSelectionIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []


        let currentDate = Date()
        
        let midnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: currentDate)

        for offset in 0 ..< 24{
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: offset, to: midnight)!
            entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, configuration: configuration))

        }
        
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
        
}
```

Comment: How do you know if it fails to reload? Do you render the refresh date in the widget and wait for 1 hour?

Comment: I'm displaying the current device time on the widget and manually setting the device time 59 minutes ahead to test it.

Comment: Why not just set from the current date? Not the start of the day?

Answer (score 1):

WidgetKit renders the views for all the entries when `getTimeline()` returns, so if you're rendering the current time in each entry then they'll all show the same time.

If you render the `date` property from your `SimpleEntry` instead of the current time then you should see it change.

I suspect it works when you change the device time manually because WidgetKit calls `getTimeline()` again.